# OPENMP_why it is so slow in write array, how could I make it fast?

Tags: c, arrays, openmp

```
//serial enum sort
double serial_enum_sort(int a[], int at[])
{
    double t1, t2;
    t1 = omp_get_wtime();
    int k, i, j;
    for(i = 1; i <= MAXN; i++)
    {
        k = 1;
        for(j = 1; j <= MAXN; j++)
            if(a[i] > a[j] || (a[i] == a[j] && i>j))
                k++;
        at[k] = a[i];
    }
    t2 = omp_get_wtime();
    return (t2 - t1);
}


// parallel enum sort
double parallel_enum_sort(int b[], int bt[])
{
    double t1, t2;
    t1 = omp_get_wtime();
    int k, i, j, id;
    #pragma omp parallel  private(k, i, j, id)
    {
        id = omp_get_thread_num()+1;
        // printf("%d\n", id);
        for(i = id; i <= MAXN; i += NUM_THREADS)
        {
            k = 1;
            for(j = 1; j <= MAXN;  j++)
                if(b[i] > b[j] || (b[i] == b[j] && i > j))
                    k++;
            bt[k] = b[i];
        }
    }
    t2 = omp_get_wtime();
    return (t2 - t1);
}
```

it's an enum_sort programme with openmp. I think          bt[k] = b[i]         cost most time. How can I improve it? My compiler is gcc4.8.2 and my OS is Linux mint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you have declared a parallel region, with the pragma

```
#pragma omp parallel  private(k, i, j, id)
```

but not declared any parallel *worksharing*.  You would do this, possibly, by replacing

```
for(i = id; i <= MAXN; i += NUM_THREADS)
```

with

```
#pragma omp for
for(i = id; i <= MAXN; i += NUM_THREADS)
```

As it stands the program you've shown us executes in parallel but all threads do the whole task - the work is not shared.  You could also write one pragma

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(k, i, j, id)
```

and make the necessary adjustments to the rest of the code; for example the `for` statement has to be on the next line.

Note: I haven't checked that your code will, without further modification, execute correctly and quickly.

Comment: 3q for your amazing answer!

Comment: Your answer is wrong. His code does do worksharing. It's the same as `pragma omp for schedule(static,1)`.

Comment: Hmmm...my answer is wrong as well. I'm right about the schedule(static,1) but the rest of my answer is bogus. Too bad I can't delete accepted an accepted answer. I'm going to have to fix it now. –  Z boson 12 mins ago

Comment: @svtter, I don't mind you changing the accepted answer but the first part of HPM's answer here is wrong and he has not fixed it yet. Obviously each thread does not do the whole task since each of them increments by `NUM_THREADS` instead of by 1. Why don't you print the thread id and iteration for `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)` and compare with your code (see the comment in my answer for the code to do this).

Comment: @svtter, this shows that `schedule(static,1)` is the same as you have done http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86e9b31a505a538d. The thread and index is exactly the same.

Comment: Indeed, `i = id; i <= MAXN; i += NUM_THREADS` is really a sort of worksharing.

Comment: @VladimirF, yes, it's the same as `schedule(static,1)`. And applying `#pragma omp for` to `for(i = id; i <= MAXN; i += NUM_THREADS)` is silly.

Comment: @Zboson but it's not wrong. His answer did solve my problems. And your answer not. Maybe you should give me a better key, and I will choose you.